# How to install Mysql 5.7.30 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am installing MySQL 5.7.30 on Ubuntu 20.04. When I run:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
```

this is the output:

```
(Reading database ... 74194 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.16-1) over (0.8.16-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.16-1) ...
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
OK
```

Can anybody explain how to avoid this warning and what does it mean? I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 3):

The `mysql` version is upgraded from `5.7.30` to `5.7.33` in mysql repository. It can be installed on `focal` from `bionic` repository.

You can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config` to setup the repository.

Also you can manually edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` as follow:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
```

In case you haven't added  the gpg key , you can see the official docs to verify and add the mysql gpg :  [2.1.4.2 Signature Checking Using GnuPG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-gpg-signature.html)

To prevent `mysql-apt-config` from overwriting `mysql.list, it can be removed.`

Then run :

```
sudo apt update
apt policy mysql-server
```

sample output:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3
  Version table:
     8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

To install it run:

```
sudo apt install mysql-community-client=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04
sudo apt install mysql-client=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04
sudo apt install mysql-server=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, but `sudo apt install mysql-community-client=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04` gives me errors
`Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-client_5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: I get the same error!

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633960/153195