# Install srvadmin-hapi package on docker container

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker

I'm attempting to install the [Dell openmanage tools](http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/) on an ubuntu 20.04 docker container and I'm running into some issues.

Dell's provided guide:

```
echo 'deb http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/950/focal focal main' | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 1285491434D8786F
gpg -a --export 1285491434D8786F | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install srvadmin-all
```

When I run this I get the following error during the step to configure srvadmin-hapi:

```
Setting up srvadmin-hapi (9.5.0) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package srvadmin-hapi (--configure):
 installed srvadmin-hapi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 srvadmin-hapi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Full output of the `apt-get install srvadmin-all` command is [here](https://gist.github.com/jessebutryn/9e4a0d2b04a12fe56524754d4d35e8f0).

---

I've also tried downloading the [individual package](https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/950/focal/pool/main/s/srvadmin-hapi/srvadmin-hapi_9.5.0_amd64.deb) but I'm not sure if I can modify it in any way to not use systemd.

Is there any way for me to get this package to install on an ubuntu docker container?

Comment: It’s a shame the Dell packages don’t use Debian’s systemd support for pre-installation service policies (which is also available in Ubuntu), it would avoid this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/srvadmin-hapi.postinst` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/true
```

As said @jesse_b  the `srvadmin-hapi.postinst` may be overwritten in the first attempt, consider modified it back again.

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install srvadmin-hapi
```

If the above instruction doesn't work, backup then edit the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` by removing `srvadmin-hapi` with its description then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install srvadmin-hapi
```

Comment: `gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 1285491434D8786F` doesn't support anymore. I tried with `sudo wget https://linux.dell.com/repo/pgp_pubkeys/0x1285491434D8786F.asc` . Followed the step mentioned still it didn't work. I am seeing the same issue.