# Java Error when trying to install snapd

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, snap

I recently tried to install snapd on my Debian 10 VPS, when I encountered this error:

```
Setting up jdk1.8 (1.8.0271-1) ...
Unpacking JAR files...
        tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/lib/tools.pack
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/deploy.pack
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
update-alternatives: error: alternative jar can't be slave of java: it is a master alternative
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8 (--configure):
 installed jdk1.8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcA7o.png)

It seems like something is wrong with my update alternatives or the java installation. I already tried searching the prompt: `alternative jar can't be slave of java: it is a master alternative`
but I can't make any sense out of it. I already tried updating my packages but this also doesnt seem to have an effect on it.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

```
alternative jar can't be slave of java: it is a master alternative
```

You need to add java to `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/bin/java 100
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271-amd64/bin/javac 100 \
--slave "/usr/bin/jar" "jar" "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_271/bin/jar"
```

To solve the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package jdk1.8 (--configure):
 installed jdk1.8 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk1.8
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[See this answer on U&L.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633960/153195)

Comment: sadly I get an error when running the second update alternatives command
It says 'update-alternatives: error: alternative jar can't be slave of javac: it is a master alternative'. Do you have any idea why?