# Install srvadmin-hapi package on Ubuntu 18.04 docker container is not working

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker

As per Dell Documentation https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/ I am trying to install `Dell OpenManage tools` in Ubuntu 18.04 container .

```
sudo echo 'deb http://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/940/bionic bionic main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list
sudo wget https://linux.dell.com/repo/pgp_pubkeys/0x1285491434D8786F.asc
sudo apt-key add 0x1285491434D8786F.asc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y srvadmin-idracadm8
```

But I am getting below error

```
Setting up srvadmin-hapi (9.4.0) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
dpkg: error processing package srvadmin-hapi (--configure):
 installed srvadmin-hapi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 srvadmin-hapi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I looked into the solution [Install srvadmin-hapi package on docker container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633544/install-srvadmin-hapi-package-on-docker-container) . But used command `gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 1285491434D8786F` is not working getting `gpg: keyserver receive failed: no name` .

As per https://linux.dell.com/repo/community/openmanage/ we should use `sudo wget https://linux.dell.com/repo/pgp_pubkeys/0x1285491434D8786F.asc` to add repository key.

Comment: Your error literally says that the system has not been booted with systemd... is this a container that has no systemd? Can you verify?

Comment: Yes its already there in the container. I tried to install `sudo apt-get install systemd` got `Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree  
     
Reading state information... Done

systemd is already the newest version (237-3ubuntu10.41).

systemd set to manually installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: `systemd --version`
`systemd 237`
`+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid`